# Playwright Logical expect

Tags: playwright

I have two headings on the page and I need to make sure that either the one or the other exists in the page.

```
let heading = page.getByRole('heading', {name: 'MyFirstHeading'});
let heading2 = page.getByRole('heading', {name: 'MySecondHeading'});
await expect(heading).toBeVisible();
```

What I tried and worked:

```
try {
    await expect(page.getByRole('heading', {name: 'MyFirstHeading'})).toBeVisible();
} catch (error) {
    await expect(page.getByRole('heading', {name: 'MySecondHeading'})).toBeVisible();
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because nothing is asked.

Answer (score 0):

While clarification on what is wanted would be could, I believe the user is asking for other ways to do this...perhaps.  I offer this - [playwright retrying](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#retrying):

```
const heading = page.getByRole('heading', { name: 'MyFirstHeading' });
const heading2 = page.getByRole('heading', { name: 'MySecondHeading' });

await expect(async () => {
  const headingIsVisible = await heading.isVisible();
  const heading2IsVisible = await heading2.isVisible();

  expect(headingIsVisible || heading2IsVisible).toBeTruthy();      }
}).toPass({
 timeout: 30000,
});
```